# How can i use the random function with variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want creating a random number generator which allows to define the min and max.

How can i fix this code :

```
import random 

print ('min =')
MIN = input()
print ('max =')
MAX = input()

print (random.randrange(MIN, MAX))
```

Comment: ... Have you tried to debug this at all? The error should be pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to change the string input to integer. See the below code snippet :

```
import random 
print ('min =')
MIN = int(input())
print ('max =')
MAX = int(input())
print (random.randrange(MIN, MAX))
```

Also your code might not gonna run if minimum is greater than maximum. So better handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an Exception (an error) is raised in your code, the program stops runnning and displays an error message.

In this case it might have shown the following message on your screen:

```
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()
```

This is the way Python tells you that you did something wrong. In fact, you already got a hint of what to do to solve it: **[the function randrange() only accepts integer arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers)**.

First you might take a look at Exceptions in The Python Standard Library, and understand what the exception [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) (the one raised in this case) actually means. Also, take a look at the definition of the [input() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), and what it really does to whatever the user sent through the prompt.

Then, try running your code again, but assigning your variables like this:

```
MIN = int(input())
MAX = int(input())
```